# AngularJS Typeahead on non selection

Tags: angularjs

I have added Angular Bootstrap's Typeahead. It is working fine and I want to add one functionality to it. So when an item is selected I want to toggle the disability of other components only if something is selected in Typeahead. The problem is, if I type something in the first Typeahead and I don't select anything, it doesn't fire any event.

Here is the html for the component. What I want to ask is which event should I listen to, to achieve this functionality?

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-controller="CitiesSearchController">
            <input type="text" id="cityCombo" ng-model="selectedCityName" placeholder="City"
                   data-typeahead="cities.CityName for cities in getCities($viewValue)"
                   data-typeahead-loading="loadingCities"
                   data-typeahead-min-length="1"
                   data-typeahead-wait-ms="0"
                   data-typeahead-on-select="onCitySelect($item, $model, $label)"
                   class="form-control" />
            <span ng-show="loadingCities" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
```

What I am thinking is this: I can fire a ng-changed event. So, whenever the text is changed it fires and event and on that basis I other components disabled. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? When the user doesn't select from the list, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Whenever the text is being edited (that is when the selection is not made) I want the other components to be disabled. So here I am selecting cities, so unless a city is selected, I want area box to be disabled. Which can of course be only populated if a city is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the change in your ng-model value, by calling `$watch` on `selectedCityName`:

**Working Plunker here:** http://plnkr.co/edit/sieXxn?p=preview

```
  $scope.$watch("selectedCityName", function(value) {

      $scope.isDisabled = value ? true : false;

  });
```

One very important thing to notice here, is that, in my example, I have set `typeahead-editable="false"` to prevent invalid selections and limit them to the ones in the original array. Consequently, **the $watch event will not fire unless a valid selection is made**. You can of course change that to `true`, but this will allow any dummy input in your `ng-model` which I believe is not valid.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please see my comment to John C. above.

Comment: Why don't you do it the other way around? Disable the controls and enable them upon valid selection only?

Comment: @DianaNassar If the user makes a valid selection and then decides to continue typing, the controls would be enabled. It sounds like huber.duber wants everything disabled while the user is typing.

Comment: @JoshC. true, but he won't be able to click on anything. And if he enters invalid value they will get disabled immediately; so even if they got indeed enabled, they will get enabled momentarily and it will have no effect as the user won't be able to click/enter anything.

Comment: Your solution is valid for my scenario if I switch the above statement to: $scope.isDisabled = value ? false : true;